# Making a specific package work in Flash

Tags: flash

I'd really like to use this package in Flash as3:

http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2010/playback-mp3-loop-gapless/

I've copied the source and saved it as a file called MP3Loop.as. In the same folder I have a .fla with some code in it like this:

```
var looper:MP3Loop = new MP3Loop();
```

So far as I can see this should be all I need to have a play with the package, but it doesn't seem to work. Instead I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at MP3Loop/initUI() at MP3Loop() at
>   loop_test_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Can anybody suggest anything else I can try? Help much appreciated!

Here is the initUI code:

```
private function initUI():void
{
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    textField.selectable = false;
    textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( 'Verdana', 10, 0xFFFFFF );
    textField.text = 'loading...';
    addChild( textField );
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything on the timeline? Specifically any ActionScript?

Comment: So what file is your new MP3Loop() call in? And what is your document class set to?

Answer (score 0):

The stage is null because the Sprite is not added to the stage. In order to use the class, you need to set the Document class to MP3Loop in the properties panel and remove your time line code.

Comment: This unravels a lot of mysteries. I hadn't come across the document class before.